# Math label >= does not render properly in R 4.2.2

Tags: r

In R v3.6.1 and v4.1.0, this renders the sign '>=' properly: `plot(1:10, main = parse(text = "0.2 >= 0.1"))`.
However, in R v4.2.2, I just get an empty square instead.

---

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Comment: Have you tried unicode ? `paste("\u2265")`

Comment: It is rendered correctly in my R v4.2.1.  The 4.2.2 change log https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2022/000686.html says "The LaTeX style for producing the PDF manuals, Rd.sty, now loads
      the standard amsmath, amsfonts and amssymb packages for greater
      coverage of math commands " .. perhaps related

Comment: @YacineHajji Yeah, unicode might be the easiest solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue under R version 4.2.2, either when printing the plot in window or exporting as tif or png formats. Exporting the figure as pdf (using pdf() function) solved the problem for me. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `showtext::showtext_auto()` before seems to solve this issue..

However, it seems to also change the size of the font..